# Is there a option in highcharts like the 'ordinal' in highstock?

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I use highchart and could need the option 'ordinal' like in highstock.
So, my xAxis is a datetime axis and the data loads out of a database. On weekends, there are no data available, but the gaps between the data-points should always be the same.
[This is the option in highstock](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal)

Does anybody know how I can realise this without using highstock?
I tried with using categories instead of datetime, but there are too much data-points, so they all overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ordinal` property requires Highstock. You can us it in Highcharts only with Highstock library. See [FAQ](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#highstock-features-in-highcharts).